# Know-how on Woocommerce product display

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm unsure if this question is relevant on stackoverflow, but I've looked almost everywhere else.

I'm looking to create a a product display, containing 6 products, on the right hand side of a picture like [this example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9oAZ.jpg)

I'm hoping some of you have some know-how you'd like to share with me on this.

Thanks in advance

A.P.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is add a left sidebar to your shop page, which can be typically done through your theme, and then add an image widget to that sidebar. The last thing to do is change the CSS code of your shop to make the whole page full-width and then make the sidebar 50% of the parent div.

This approach has the advantage that the sidebar is showed after the products in mobile mode (by default), so mobile visitors will first see the products.